# Rename `spring-tools-suite` to `springsource-tool-suite`

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

Can someone with enough reputation please rename the [`spring-tools-suite`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-tools-suite/info) tag to `springsource-tool-suite`?

Here is the reason:  Spring Tools Suite is an incorrect name for the product.  SpringSource Tool Suite is appropriate.  See the website here: http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts.

Please note that the `spring-tools-suite` tag is not used as often as the `sts` tag.  This question is related to the one here: [Ambiguous tag: sts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78923/ambiguous-tag-sts) Where a user suggests that we remove the `sts` tag since it is ambiguous.

Comment: Please rename or retag to "**sts-springsource-tools-suite**".  See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78923/ambiguous-tag-sts/81485#81485) for reasons.  Also note the plural "tools".

Comment: Makes sense.  Also, that was a typo, should be springsource-tool-suite.  Fixed it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this yourself, it just takes a few minutes work.

- Per [this answer to "Ambiguous tag: sts"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78923/ambiguous-tag-sts/81485#81485), retag all [spring-tools-suite](/questions/tagged/spring-tools-suite) questions to [sts-springsource-tools-suite](/questions/tagged/sts-springsource-tools-suite).  Note that you will be creating the new tag in the process -- which you have enough SO rep for.
- For each [sts](/questions/tagged/sts) question, retag it as [sts-springsource-tools-suite](/questions/tagged/sts-springsource-tools-suite) or [sts-security-token-service](/questions/tagged/sts-security-token-service), as appropriate.
- In a day or two, the old unused tags will drop out of the system.  (Or so I was told in answer to one of my questions.)
- Create appropriate synonyms if questions continue to get mis-tagged (you'll need more rep for that).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I only recently received tag creation privileges, so I am now able to do it.